# Why didn't Obito turn blind?

Tags: anime, naruto

I'm curious to learn why Obito didn't turn blind when he used the *Mangekyō Sharingan*?

[image]

Comment: Now you can answer it yourself!

Comment: How is this question unclear? The wiki clearly indicates that one of the side-effects of using this device is blindness.

Comment: @Valorum It was extremely unclear before the edit.  I'll add my reopen.

Comment: @Radhil - Frustratingly, it was edited *before* it got closed. A classic case of robo-reviewing by inexperienced users.

Comment: Related question in Anime & Manga SE: [How does the Mangekyo Sharingan blind its wielder, and why are some wielders not blinded?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3029/310)

Answer (score 3):

**It was because he was injected with Hashirama's cells.**

**[Background](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRZYebZW3BE&t=2s):** Madara, defeated by Hashirama Senju, took a big bite from Hashirama before he died. However, he implanted *Izanami* to one of his mangekyou sharingan to alter reality, such that he was back alive. He used Hashirama's cells from the chunk he bit off to cultivated more cells and treated himself with those cells to elongate his lifespan.

Madara found Obito after he was crushed under a boulder and treated him with cells he cultivated from Hashirama Senju. Apparently, those cells not only elongate one's lifespan and heal very fast, but also suppress the side effects of excessive mangekyou sharingan use.

This may be one of the several reasons:

- Hashirama Senju was most famous for his healing jutsus. Any wound he received healed seemingly effortlessly.
- Hashirama Senju was the reincarnation of Asura.
- Hashirama Senju could use the wood release, the only release that can create life.

Comment: what about Kakashi?

Comment: @Erosennin Two theories: Either Kakashi rarely uses it or he doesn't go blind because the eye actually belongs to Obito who has Hashirama'a cells. They share the same space-time, they are activated at the same time due to Obito so they might share the same health as well.